# How to run dos2unix on all files with all extensions in a directory and its sun-directories?

Tags: dos2unix

Say I am in a folder named `Folder`. This folder have several files with different file types, and several subfolders called, `SubFolder1`, `SubFolder2`, etc. Each of these subfolders have files and subfolders inside them. I want to run dos2unix on ALL files in Folder, no matter they are in the main folder or in one of several sub-directores. Absolutely everything. How can I do that? To my knowledge, running

> dos2unix *

works only on the files located in the main folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## First solution (general)

[The standard `find` program](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is designed precisely for that kind of tasks. Something along the lines of:

```sh
find Folder/ -type f -exec dos2unix '{}' '+'
```

This command

1. explores `Folder/` recursively,
2. selects all files which are of type `f` (regular files, by contrast with directories, symbolic links and other types of special files),
3. and executes `dos2unix` with all selected filenames.

`'{}'` is a placeholder which indicates where in the command you want the filename(s) to be inserted, and `'+'` terminates the said command. You can also run `dos2unix` *once for each* filename (by changing `'+'` with `';'`), but since `dos2unix` accepts an arbitrary number of input arguments, it’s better to use it (as it avoids spawning many processes).

`find` has many more options, you can find them in the manual page (link above).

## Second solution (specific to your problem)

If your shell is Bash, Bash supports recursive wildcards (other shells such as zsh probably have a similar feature). It is disabled by default, so you have to change a shell option:

```sh
shopt -s globstar
```

Then, `**` is a wildcard that selects everything *recursively* (including directories and other special files, so you may need to filter it). After that, you can try:

```sh
dos2unix Folder/**
```

If you want the wildcard to actually select absolutely everything, including filenames starting with a dot (hidden files), you’ll also need to set another option: `shopt -s dotglob`.

Comment: thank you very much! Now another question: what if I want to run dos2unix on all of .sh files (again in all folders and subfolders)?

Comment: @tajir12457 add `-name '*.sh'` to `find` options before `-exec`. The `find` program can filter files using many different criteria, including filename, modification date and so on. Again see the manual page for all available criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Dos2unix manual
http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/dos2unix.htm#RECURSIVE-CONVERSION

**RECURSIVE CONVERSION**

In a Unix shell the find(1) and xargs(1) commands can be used to run dos2unix recursively over all text files in a directory tree. For instance to convert all .txt files in the directory tree under the current directory type:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -print0 |xargs -0 dos2unix
```

The find(1) option -print0 and corresponding xargs(1) option -0 are needed when there are files with spaces or quotes in the name. Otherwise these options can be omitted. Another option is to use find(1) with the -exec option:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

In a Windows Command Prompt the following command can be used:

```
for /R %G in (*.txt) do dos2unix "%G"
```

PowerShell users can use the following command in Windows PowerShell:

```
get-childitem -path . -filter '*.txt' -recurse | foreach-object {dos2unix $_.Fullname}
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution is to use xargs. Care should be taken to account for the filenames with spaces. This is done with the -print0 and -0 options.
Find all the *.sh files that require the conversion:

```
find -name '*.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix -ic
```

Run the conversion:

```
find -name '*.sh' -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```